# What's the mode of a bivariate Poisson distribution?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I have been looking at the bivariate Poisson distribution of the form as it is described at Wikipedia:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution#Bivariate_Poisson_distribution

I was now wondering if there is close form expression for the mode of this distribution. I know the mode of the univariate Poisson distribution is $\lfloor \lambda\rfloor$.

Thanks for any feedback!

Answer (score 3):

Let $Y_0$, $Y_1$, and $Y_2$ be mutually stochastically independent Poisson random variables, with positive parameters $\lambda_0$, $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$, respectively. Then, a non-trivial bivariate Poisson distribution is the joint distribution of $X_1$ and $X_2$ where:

$$X_1 = Y_1 + Y_0$$
$$X_2 = Y_2 + Y_0$$

with joint pmf:

$$f(x_1,x_2) = \frac{e^{(-\lambda_0 - \lambda_1 -\lambda_2)} \lambda _0^{x_1} \left(-\lambda _2\right)^{-x_1} \lambda _2^{x_2} }{x_1!x_2!} U\left(-x_1,1-x_1+x_2,-\frac{\lambda _1 \lambda _2}{\lambda _0}\right)$$

defined on $x_i \in {0, 1, \dots}$, and where $U(.)$ denotes the confluent hypergeometric function. Finally, let $(x_1^m,x_2^m)$ denote the bivariate mode ... *i.e.*, the value of $(x_1,x_2)$ at which $f(x_1,x_2)$ is a maximum.

**A Natural Starting Point**

Correctly, the mode of each *univariate* Poisson distribution is:

$$ \begin{cases}\lfloor \lambda_i \rfloor & \text{if } \lambda_i \text{ is not an integer }  \\ \lambda_i - 1 \text{ and } \lambda_i \text{ (two modes)} & \text{if } \lambda_i  \text{ is an integer } \end{cases}$$

Because the sum of independent Poisson random variables is itself Poisson, the marginal pmf of $X_1 = Y_1 + Y_0$ is $Poisson(\lambda_1 + \lambda_0)$, and similarly, the marginal pmf of $X_2 = Y_2 + Y_0$ is $Poisson(\lambda_2 + \lambda_0)$.

Then, a natural starting point (at least for the general non-integer parameter case) is that the bivariate mode might be located at $(\lfloor \lambda_1 + \lambda_0 \rfloor, \lfloor \lambda_2 + \lambda_0 \rfloor)$.

**More Complicated than that ...**

However, there are good theoretical reasons why the mode might *not* be exactly (or uniquely) defined by: $(\lfloor \lambda_1 + \lambda_0 \rfloor, \lfloor \lambda_2 + \lambda_0 \rfloor)$ . In particular, since:

$$corr(X_1,X_2) = \frac{\lambda_0}{\sqrt{(\lambda_0+\lambda_1) (\lambda_0+\lambda_2)}}$$

... the positive correlation between $X_1$ and $X_2$ may shift the density mass away from the modes of the marginal distributions.

For an algebraic test of modality, in a discrete world one typically looks at a ratio such as $\frac{f(x_1,x_2)}{f(x_1+1,x_2+1)}$ to see where it is greater than 1 etc. But the HypergeometricU function makes this seemingly intractable.

But, it is even more complicated than that, as a quick numerical investigation reveals peculiar non-monotonic behaviour. For example:

- When $(\lambda_0 = 4.99, \lambda_1 = 3.1, \lambda_2 = 2.493)$ $\to$ mode is: $(x_1=8,x_2=7)$
- When $(\lambda_0 = 4.99, \lambda_1 = 3.1, \lambda_2 = 2.494)$ $\to$ mode is: $(x_1=7,x_2=7)$

... so a tiny *increase* in $\lambda_2$ can actually sometimes cause $x_1^m$ to *DECREASE*, while $x_2^m$ remains unchanged. [ These calculations were performed using exact methods with all numbers represented as EXACT symbolic pure integers, *i.e.* 2.494 represented as 2494/1000 in *Mathematica*, to avoid any possibility of numerical or rounding error. ]

This unfortunately suggests that the prospect of obtaining a definitive theoretical derivation seems remote ... As such, I have proceeded further with a numerical exploration.

**BivariatePoissonMode**

Here is some *Mathematica* code that finds the mode by evaluating the pmf $f(x_1,x_2)$ at all possible combinations of $x_1$ and $x_2$, and selecting the combination that yields the maximum:

```
BivariatePoissonMode[a0_, a1_, a2_] := 
 Module[{f, x1, x2, m01 = Floor[a0 + a1], m02 = Floor[a0 + a2]}, 
  f = ((1/(x1!*x2!))*a0^x1*a2^x2*Exp[-a0 - a1 - a2]*
            HypergeometricU[-x1, 1 - x1 + x2, -((a1*a2)/a0)])/(-a2)^x1; 
  Rest[First[Sort[
          Flatten[Table[{f, x1, x2}, 
               {x1, Max[0, m01 - 3], m01 + 3}, {x2, Max[m02 - 3, 0], m02 + 3}], 1], 
        #1[[1]] > #2[[1]] & ]]]]
```

For example, given $(\lambda_0 = 2,\lambda_1 = 3, \lambda_2 = 4)$:

```
BivariatePoissonMode[2,3,4]
```

returns the mode at:

> {4,5}

```
BivariatePoissonMode[2.2, 3.2, 4.2]
```

returns the mode at:

> {5,6}

If one wants to check the entire parameter space under the plot, one can do so -- although this is not an efficient way to proceed ... In the above, the function has been set to evaluate all possible $x_1$ and $x_2$ values plus or minus 3 integers from the optimal solution derived below.

**Summary results**

The above function was mapped over 1 million strictly non-integer combinations of  $(\lambda_0,\lambda_1, \lambda_2)$ each ranging from approximately 0.1 to 35, and separately 64000 integer combinations of $(\lambda_0,\lambda_1, \lambda_2)$ each ranging from 1 to 40.

The result is that, within the numerical grid search, and without exception:

---

- For strictly *integer-valued* parameters, the mode is:

$$(x_1^m,x_2^m) = (\lambda_1 + \lambda_0 -1,  \lambda_2 + \lambda_0 -1)$$

- For any parameter set that contains *non-integers*, the mode is:

$$(x_1^m, x_2^m) = (\lfloor \lambda_1 + \lambda_0 \rfloor - \delta_1,  \lfloor \lambda_2 + \lambda_0 \rfloor - \delta_2 ) \text{ where } \delta_i = 0 \text{ or } 1$$

---

As discussed above, it appears that it will be difficult to find a purely deterministic explanation of the $\delta_i$ behaviour. On the positive side, the bivariate Poisson mode can practically be found by testing $f(x_1,x_2)$ at just 4 combinations of $(x_1,x_2)$.

**Other**

Unlike the univariate case, the bivariate mode appears to always be unique.

Based on 1 million grid tests of non-integer combinations of $(\lambda_0,\lambda_1,\lambda_2)$:

- $\delta_1 = 0$ and $\delta_2 = 0$, $\to \text{ roughly } 70$% of the parameter space
- $\delta_1 = 0$ and $\delta_2 = 1$, $\to \text{ roughly } 12$% of the parameter space
- $\delta_1 = 1$ and $\delta_2 = 0$, $\to \text{ roughly } 12$% of the parameter space
- $\delta_1 = 1$ and $\delta_2 = 1$, $\to \text{ roughly }  5$% of the parameter space

This is also something I would like to check for stability when I have more time.

Comment: Impressive work. +1